# Basic Python Function Definition Question

Tags: python

I am a newly learning python I had a question for the community regarding Python function definitions or personal made function definition I am doing an exercise where you make a function that takes an input in celsius and spits out the conversion in Fahrenheit I've made a successful function but for some reason this one does not run correctly when I save it as a script and run it in the python terminal I get nothing. appreciate any help.

```
def TempChange():

    print("Input Cel Value")

    Cel = input()

    Cel = float(Cel)

    print ("transfering to fair value")

    Fair = (Cel * 9 / 5 + 32)

    print(Fair)

    while True:
        break
```

if I run the code without the `def` function at the top it works fine and chapgpt3 tells me there's errors but spits out the same code

I tried without the `def` function on top and it worked as I expected it to.

Comment: "and chapgpt3 tells me there's errors but spits out the same code"—ugh, _please_ don't listen to anything that comes out of that thing. It is _not intelligent_.

Comment: Any time you talk about "errors", please include the exact, complete, error message, verbatim.

Comment: Did you run the function? Include a line with “TempChange()”

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but for some reason this one does not run correctly when I save it as a script and run it in the python terminal I get nothing" To be clear: in your own words, you expect that if you put **only** this code in a file and run it **as is**, the `TempChange` function will run? Why? What exactly do you think is the purpose of writing a function? (Hint: notice how the code says things like `Cel = input()` and `print("Input Cel Value")`? Notice how `input` and `print` functions **are not** automatically called every time you start Python? Why do you suppose that is?)

Comment: Please also read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We cannot offer "any help" as that is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236); we are looking for a clear, specific question - asked in properly organized sentences with proper punctuation and capitalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between defining a function and *calling* it.

The code inside a function definition is only executed when the code is *called*.

If I create a file "hello.py" as below, and execute it, nothing happens because I haven't called any function(s).

```
def hello():
  print("hello")
```

Now, if I change that file to include a function call:

```
def hello():
  print("hello")

hello()
```

*Now* executing this program will print `hello` to standard output.

Comment: Ahh okay that would make sense. Thanks so much for the feedback I appreciate it